# Strange window size(Please look screenshot)

Tags: interface

Blender window size is strange...
I can't see the top of window.(but I can click it(ex. "File" "Edit" etc...). I can't see it but I can click it because it misaligned.)
I tried these:
* Reinstall
* Change the option of graphic driver
* install another version blender 
But I can't fix this...
[image]